# TypeError: Array.prototype.unshift called on null or undefined

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I cannot figure out why I am getting the error below from this code:

```
var xs = [1, 2, 3];
var ys = [];
_.each(xs, ys.unshift);
console.log(ys);
```

The error is: `Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.unshift called on null or undefined`.

I am using underscore.js. I tried

```
_.each(xs, _.bind(Array.prototype.unshift, xs));
```

but this resulted in something I did not expect at all:

```
[3, 2, Array[3], 2, 1, Array[3], 1, 0, Array[3]]
```

where the sub-arrays are actually what I wanted: `[1, 2, 3]`.

the only variation that worked is:

```
_.each(xs, function (x) { ys.unshift(x); });
```

But I wanted to pretend that I am using a functional language and just supply the function to `each`...

Please help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What output are you expecting and why can't you just use [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead?

Comment: well, I can use `concat`. thanks. I was trying to understand why my code did not work, not that I did not know how to implement this another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interesting.
this is because `_.each` calls the callback with `value, key, arr` which binds this values to the array:

```
_.each(xs, function (value, key, xs) {
  ys.unshift(value, key, xs);
});
```

I don't think underscore has a helper the will run a function only with N parameters regardless of what you pass

So, this would work, even tho you were looking for a cleaner version:

```
_.each(xs, function (value, key, xs) {
  ys.unshift(value);
});
```

An implementation could look like:

```
function bond(fn, ctx, numArgs) {
  return function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, numArgs);
    return fn.apply(ctx, args);
  }
}

_.each(xs, bond(ys.unshift, ys, 1));
```

Comment: this gives the same result as the one with `Array.prototype.unshift`: http://plnkr.co/edit/JQXfCTD5DhSzceByiUnk?p=preview

Comment: oh... `unshift` perhaps un-shifts all given parameters, not just the first one. right.. thanks.